# How to write shell script to set to execute command for some exact time?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to start `repo sync` command to download some sources from internet. But I want to start that command on the server after 12.00 am (at the mid night). how to do it? any shell script to do that?

Comment: That is what [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is for.

Comment: If you want to do it repeatedly (eg, every night), use `cron`.  If you want to do it once, use `at`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), check this site it can help you understand it better: https://crontab.guru/

This could also be useful https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-cron.html

Depending on your use case probably the [AT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(Unix)) command also could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week command

For midnight every day:

step 1:   crontab -e        /* edit cron file */

step 2:   add the entry below

0 0 * * * reposync -options

step 3:  save file.

step 4:  crontab  -l   /* list cron jobs */